# Get value without knowing key in one-pair-associative-array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

There is an associative array with **only one** pair `key=>value`.

I don't know it's key, but I need to get it's value:

```
$array = array('???' => 'value');
$value = // ??
```

`$array[0]` doesn't work.

How can I get it's value?

Comment: As you can see, there's several good answers, the most terse I believe is end(), as @nickb posted.

Comment: agreed, it is more "ninja" then `array_keys`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can also do either of the following functions to get the value since there's only one element in the array.

```
$value = reset( $array);
$value = current( $array);
$value = end( $array);
```

Also, if you want to use `array_keys()`, you'd need to do:

```
$keys = array_keys( $array);
echo $array[ $keys[0] ];
```

To get the value.

As some more options, you can ALSO use `array_pop()` or `array_shift()` to get the value:

```
$value = array_pop( $array);
$value = array_shift( $array);
```

Finally, you can use `array_values()` to get all the values of the array, then take the first:

```
$values = array_values( $array);
echo $values[0];
```

---

Of course, there are lots of other alternatives; some silly, some useful.

```
$value = pos($array);
$value = implode('', $array);
$value = current(array_slice($array, 0, 1));
$value = current(array_splice($array, 0, 1));
$value = vsprintf('%s', $array);
foreach($array as $value);
list(,$value) = each($array);
```

Comment: I think those are all the options available.

Answer (score 5):

[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will get the key for you

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
echo $array[$keys[0]];
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to retrieve the first item?

```
$value = reset($array);
$key = key($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_values

```
$newArray = array_values($array);
echo $newArray[0];
```