# foreach without doing a loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

How is it possible to perform a `foreach` function without doing a loop for example

```
foreach($result['orders'] as $order) {
```

But I don't want to do a foreach I want something like

```
$result['orders'] == $order;
```

Or something like that instead of doing it inside an loop because `$result['orders']` is only returning 1 result anyway so I don't see the point in doing it in a loop.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If there's only one, just access it `$result['orders'][0]`

Comment: I'm trying to get information from an API which is stored inside $result['orders'] so you could say it's an array, but i don't want to do a foreach to be able to get the content

Comment: @CurtisCrewe There would be lots of ways to get at the data inside, but without seeing the structure of the array we can't say what is the best method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value without knowing key in one-pair-associative-aray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145185/get-value-without-knowing-key-in-one-pair-associative-aray)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the first (and apparently only) element in the array with any array function that gets an element from the array, e.g. [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) or [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
$order = array_shift( $result['orders']);
```

Or `list()`:

```
list( $order) = $result['orders'];
```

Or, if you know it's numerically indexed, access it directly:

```
$order = $results['orders'][0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much nick, i appreciate you taking your time to find 3 different ways.

Comment: @Curtis - There are actually a lot more, I linked a similar question, you will get a laugh from how many ways this is possible in PHP (I know I did...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe just looking for this?

```
$result['orders'] = $result['orders'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comparison operator (==) rather than an assignment operator (=) in your second code example. If you are just trying to set a variable equal to a position in an array, you can use:

`$order = $results['orders'];`

I am not sure if that is what you are trying to accomplish though.